# How to respond to AWS S3 put event triggered using Lambda and publish to MQTT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-iot

Sorry but im a total noob and only starting with AWS.

What I am trying to achieve this time is to use Lambda to respond to new item arrival to s3 by publishing message to my iot specific topic. I configured s3 and lambda and can see invocation count in Lambda console. So im assuming that part is working. What I don't understand is how to send an acknowledge message to topic on mqtt console? I'm trying to learn how Lambda works and later implement push notifications to ios or android app when new item arrives to s3. Here's an example of code which I tried to implement already.

```
import boto3
import json

client = boto3.client('iot-data', region_name='eu-west-1')

# Change topic, qos and payload
response = client.publish(
    topic='$mytopic/iot',
    qos=1,
    payload=json.dumps({"foo":"bar"})
)
```

Comment: That's not a Lambda function. Lambda functions in Python have a specific event handler function. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

def handler_name(event, context): This is the function that will be invoked by lambda. Wrap your existing code in this.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/get-started-create-function.html